# Convert dynamically generated pdf in jpg with php-imagic

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, imagick

I'm deserately trying to convert pdf files to jpeg using imagick. It's working well when i'm using this syntax :

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage('file.pdf');
$imagick->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

BUT… the pdf i want to convert is dynamically generated in pdf using TCPDF. And I'm desesperately trying to convert pdf files to jpeg using image magick. It's working well when i'm using this syntax :

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage('file.pdf');
$imagick->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

And i can't imagine to write a file each time this script is sollicited !
Any idea ?

Comment: Without seeing more code its just a guess, but perhaps readimageblob? http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php

Comment: Yep, i would also have believed readimageblob would have been a solution… but i already tried it !

Comment: Hmmmm… i got it. It's ok if the input is an absolute url. I would have prefered to have a relative url instead, but i'll deal with it !

Comment: @PhilippeC. You have given the same code example twice.